# How do I prevent user Input continuous "00" in Angular8？

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

I use Angular8 and I want prevent user Input continuous "0" in a Input element.

if user Input "00" I want it display as "0", if user input "01", I want delete the first "0" in the string => it should becomes "1".

I change the value in ngModelChange() , my problem is : the ngModel changed indeed . but the input element still display the old value.

and I have a template for it :
[Check this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jjzjx118-templateform)

and it just won't work,
can anyone tell me the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only expecting whole numbers (or you don't mind rounding down), you could use [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor). Note that this [won't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal) in strict mode.

```js
let test = Math.floor(00);
let test2 = Math.floor(01);

console.log(test, test2);
```

## Update

So this has been fun. Javascript is treating 0123 as a [binary literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Literals). Turns out forcing base10 with [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) is the way to go. Note, you *have* to be sure you are parsing a string for this to work.

```js
let test = Math.floor(00); // 0
let test2 = Math.floor(01); // 1
let test3 = Math.floor(0123); // 83
let test4 = parseInt(0123); // 83
let test5 = parseInt(0123, 10); // 83
let test6 = parseInt('0123', 10); // 123

console.log(test, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6);
```

Comment: thank you , the code works , but could you please check out my  template code ? I posted a link above. I bind input's value to a ngModel and transfer it in (ngModelChange) function, but it dose not work.